# Sun Type 7 Keyboard + KDE shortcuts: Why does the control center ignore most of the function keys on the left edge?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xkb, kde5

I've recently equipped my OpenSuSE 15.2 with KDE 5 with a Sun Type 7 keyboard and now would like to use the function keys on its left edge for a variety of system-wide shortcuts. The only issue is that in the shortcut list of KDE's control center, some of these keys are simply ignored:

[image: Shortcut key selector]

The Help, Cut, Copy, Paste, and Open keys are recognised as such, whereas Cancel, Redo, Undo, Properties, Foreground, and Find are not, and I don't know why. All of them emit their own scancodes, and `xkb` maps them to the corresponding key symbols. Here is, for instance, what the Properties key emits (output from `xev`):

```
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x7800001,
    root 0x561, subw 0x0, time 3103717, (-256,541), root:(1374,570),
    state 0x10, keycode 138 (keysym 0x1005ff70, SunProps), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

What's wrong with these keys? Here is my `xkb` config for your reference:

```
╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  setxkbmap -verbose 10
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc102
layout:     de
variant:    pl
options:    terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,altwin:meta_win,lv3:ralt_switch,compose:menu
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwertz)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+de(pl)+inet(evdev)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)+altwin(meta_win)+level3(ralt_switch)+compose(menu)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)
geometry:   pc(pc102)
```

**UPDATE:** I've looked into the current `xkb` config to find out that in the `symbols/inet` file, there is a complete block devoted to the proprietary Sun Type 6/7 function keys:

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "evdev" {
    key <MUTE>   {      [ XF86AudioMute         ]       };
    key <VOL->   {      [ XF86AudioLowerVolume  ]       };
    key <VOL+>   {      [ XF86AudioRaiseVolume  ]       };
    key <POWR>   {      [ XF86PowerOff          ]       };
    key <STOP>   {      [ Cancel                ]       }; // KDE ignores me!
    key <AGAI>   {      [ Redo                  ]       }; // KDE ignores me!
    key <PROP>   {      [ SunProps              ]       }; // KDE ignores me!
    key <UNDO>   {      [ Undo                  ]       }; // KDE ignores me!
    key <FRNT>   {      [ SunFront              ]       }; // KDE ignores me!
    key <COPY>   {      [ XF86Copy              ]       };
    key <OPEN>   {      [ XF86Open              ]       };
    key <PAST>   {      [ XF86Paste             ]       };
    key <FIND>   {      [ Find                  ]       };
    key <CUT>    {      [ XF86Cut               ]       };
    key <HELP>   {      [ Help                  ]       };
    key <LNFD>   {      [ Linefeed              ]       };
};
```

This means that the keycodes and symbols are registered in `xkb` the right way, but unfortunately, it's KDE's control center, which ignores the Sun-specific keysyms (see the comments above). **Does that mean that I'll have to file a ticket with the KDE guys?**

Comment: There are at least two sets of kb mappings for sun keyboards, and both of them are buggy for type 7 keyboards.  I've been meaning to look into how to fix that.  The sun compat set lets all the function keys on the left work but breaks media keys.

Comment: In `xkb/keycodes/evdev`, a whole section is devoted to Solaris compatibility: Keycodes #121 thru #124 (media keys in the upper right corner) as well as #136 thru #146 (function keys near the left edge) are mentioned there, but I still don't understand why the media keys and some of the left-edge keys (#141 thru #146) do work with KDE whereas the other ones do not.

Comment: On my system, the correct file is xkb/keycodes/sun

Comment: I have already changed the keyboard model to "Sun Type 6/7 (European)" in the KDE system settings, but no use: I still can't use the abovementioned keys for KDE shortcuts.

Comment: @user10489 I've already given the config another try by switching from `Generic PC Keyboard (104/105 keys)` to `Sun Type 6/7 (European)`, but this broke the Compose key, which suddenly became the Menu key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having received a handful of good hints (thank you!), I found out that it's the key symbols in the `Evdev Standardized Keycodes` section of the `symbols/inet` file, which cause trouble with KDE: Most symbols, which do **not** start with `XF86`, are ignored by KDE for some mysterious reason (a bug maybe?), so I simply replaced them with some already existing XF86 key symbols, which suit my needs best. For instance, I replaced the `Cancel` keysym of the `<STOP>` keycode with `XF86Stop`. Then, the key is recognised by KDE's hotkey definition dialog.

Answer (score 1):

There's two options for the Sun 7 keyboard provided by default

- The default Sun 7 mapping uses the key bindings you found that neither KDE nor Gnome recognize for <kbd>Cancel</kbd> <kbd>Redo</kbd> <kbd>SunProps</kbd> <kbd>Undo</kbd> <kbd>SunFront</kbd>
- The `suncompat` option binds all the left keys to function keys, but overlaps those with the top row function keys and binds <kbd>XF86AudioMute</kbd> <kbd>XF86AudioLowerVolume</kbd> <kbd>XF86AudioRaiseVolume</kbd> <kbd>XF86PowerOff</kbd> to symbols prefixed with `Sun` that neither KDE nor Gnome recognizes.

So both of the default configurations are buggy in different ways.
There are 3 possible fixes for this:

- use `xmodmap` to remap the keys correctly, but this is obsolete and is stepped on by multiple things in KDE / Gnome
- Create a new xkb binding that is correct and submit it as a bug patch (I've been meaning to do this but haven't gotten around to it -- maybe soon, and I'll update things here if I do)
- Submit a bug report for KDE and Gnome to recognize the missing symbols